# Calculate block hash is different in regtest?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-theory, hash, regtest

I'm able to calculate the block hash in mainnet and testnet, but I don't get the right hash in regtest.
I mint +3000 blocks and I get the block with height 3000

```
bitcoin-cli getblock $(bitcoin-cli getblockhash 3000)                                   

{
  "hash": "4221d8b10b0a7eb5e050337c76819abf71113f17e266e88cb12df4bf5ce24b55",
  "confirmations": 502,
  "strippedsize": 215,
  "size": 251,
  "weight": 896,
  "height": 3000,
  "version": 536870912,
  "versionHex": "20000000",
  "merkleroot": "23b4600b467f18ef0ec18bd73a9b921077486cf67c44c912de114888db184bf9",
  "tx": [
    "23b4600b467f18ef0ec18bd73a9b921077486cf67c44c912de114888db184bf9"
  ],
  "time": 1599147354,
  "mediantime": 1599147353,
  "nonce": 0,
  "bits": "207fffff",
  "difficulty": 4.656542373906925e-10,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001772",
  "nTx": 1,
  "previousblockhash": "4776b1ccad27e2de9ccbdc5bf4ad4d972a89e27a020db1f7b59abb857d77f3be",
  "nextblockhash": "121512fc6bc1395ada64a6c63ba2c2955ad9cc240a1fc0282b95cf2c2651b381"
}
```

Now I save the values in env variable

```
 ver=`printf 20000000 | tac -rs ..| tr -d '\n'`
 prev=`printf 4776b1ccad27e2de9ccbdc5bf4ad4d972a89e27a020db1f7b59abb857d77f3be | tac -rs .. | tr -d '\n'`
 mkl=`printf 23b4600b467f18ef0ec18bd73a9b921077486cf67c44c912de114888db184bf9 | tac -rs .. | tr -d '\n'`
 time=`printf '%x\n' 1599147354 | tac -rs .. | tr -d '\n'`
 bits=`echo 207fffff | tac -rs .. | tr -d '\n'`
 nonce=`printf '%x\n' 0 | tac -rs .. | tr -d '\n'`
```

After that I can concat and get the little endian representation

```
printf $ver$prev$mkl$time$bits$nonce | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b | awk '{printf $1}' | tac -rs ..
```

The result is: `09665bcb63b6c279948f93937669bf1c8f36cffda0646180ba523847cb642384`. the same operations in mainnet and testnet works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The nonce needs to be 8 hex digits** but `printf %x` only generates the minimum digits needed for the value, which for 0 is only 1 digit. (The same is true of other numeric conversions `%d %i %u %o` also.) You need to use `%08x` to force an 8-hexit value:

```
ver=$(printf 20000000 | tac -rs ..)
prev=$(printf 4776b1ccad27e2de9ccbdc5bf4ad4d972a89e27a020db1f7b59abb857d77f3be | tac -rs .. )
mkl=$(printf 23b4600b467f18ef0ec18bd73a9b921077486cf67c44c912de114888db184bf9 | tac -rs .. )
time=$(printf %x 1599147354 | tac -rs .. )
#should be %08x if any timestamp can be before mid-1978
bits=$(printf 207fffff | tac -rs .. )
nonce=$(printf %08x 0 | tac -rs .. )
printf $ver$prev$mkl$time$bits$nonce | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256 -binary |
 openssl sha256 | awk '{print $2}' | tac -rs..

-->
4221d8b10b0a7eb5e050337c76819abf71113f17e266e88cb12df4bf5ce24b55
```

Other changes:

- most of your items didn't even have a newline, and for those that did it is discarded by the `tac -rs..`, and so none of them need `|tr -d '\n'` -- although for consistency I removed the `\n` in some `printf` formats, and changed the `echo` (which adds newline by default) to `printf` (which doesn't). (And even if the/some/any items did contain newline, if you doublequote the final `printf "$ver...$nonce"` so they get treated as data and not wordsplits, the `xxd -r -p` will discard them as if they weren't there at all.)
- I used the newer syntax `$( )` for process substitution instead of the older backticks (which I can't show in Stack markdown!) because in many cases it has advantages, although not here specifically, and I like to be consistent. (There are dozens of Qs about this on other Stacks.)
- I used `openssl` instead of `sha256sum` because I have it on my systems and it's a little easier.

This wasn't a problem on mainnet and testnet, at least for most blocks, because they have difficulty high enough that the nonce value will be at least 29 bits most of the time.

Comment: thanks for your time and thanks for your super reply!

Comment: I put the script on sh file, for that reason I need `| tr -d '\n'`.
Do you have any advice to avoid | tr -d '\n' in file sh?

Comment: The code I posted _is_ in a script file (on my CentOS test system) and works fine without `tr -d '\n'` for the reasons I explained -- what makes you think it's needed?